# How to remove a single quote (apostrophe) from a string in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, apostrophe, single-quotes

I have tried the following and non of these seem to work:

```
regexprep(string, '''', '')
regexprep(string, char(39), '')
strrep(string, '''', '')
strrep(string, char(39), '')
```

I don't know what other functions to use.

E.g word: APeGs'
I would like to remove the quote ( ' ) after the word but it does nothing.

Comment: Please add some strings for testing - for a string like `string = 'hello'' hello'` it seems to work

Comment: Your first one works just fine: `regexprep('''123''', '''', '')`. Are you sure that `string` isn't a cell array and MATLAB is just showing the single quotes because of that?

Comment: Hi I have a word [ APeGs' ] in a text file and I would like to remove the single quote ( ' ) after the word but it does nothing.

Comment: Uhm, how are you calling e.g. `strrep`? Just as you posted it, or with `string = strrep(string, '''', '');`?

Comment: with string = strrep(string, '''', '');

Comment: So try the following: `string = 'APeGs'''; string = strrep(string, '''', '');` - does this work?

Comment: it works for just one word, however, I'm reading a text file and it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: So please show us what you are actually doing: how are you reading the text file? what exact functions are you calling? if we don't know what you are doing, we can't help you...